# every minute some C# method invoke (asp.net web api web)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have to run a C# method every minute. I did create a `observable` for timer and invoking it every 1 minute and this code I'm using in class constructor. Is there any other solution?

```
public Test()
{
    IObservable<long> timer = Observable
        .Defer(() =>
    {
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var result = new DateTimeOffset(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, 0, 0, now.Offset);
        result = result.AddMinutes(((now.Minute / 1) + 1) * 1);
        return Observable.Timer(result, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));
    });

    timer.Subscribe(async x =>
    {
        await InvokeMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: "Is there any other solution?" so your code works? If so, this should be posted on the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) StackExchange forum

Comment: What kind of app? (Win Forms, WPF, MVC)? .NET Core?

Comment: this is an asp.net web api app

Comment: You can also use [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A web application doesn't seem naturally suitable for a long-running background process, as it's generally at the mercy of the web server which is more designed for a request/response setup.  Something like a Windows Service, or system tray application, or Azure Function, etc. would probably be better.

Comment: You *don't* need `System.Reactive` just to call something ever 1 minute. A simple timer will do. Rx itself will use a timer. The trick is how to let ASP.NET know you have a long-running operation and prevent it from garbage-collecting the timer (or observable, or task) when a request ends

Comment: An other approach could be using the `System.Timers.Timer` it has an `Autoreset` property, so it can trigger every Minute,

Comment: Check [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1).  A [timed background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#timed-background-tasks) is one of the examples provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this is what you need:

```
public void Test()
{
    IObservable<Unit> timer =
        Observable
            .Defer(() =>
            {
                var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                var result = new DateTimeOffset(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute + 1, 0, now.Offset);
                return Observable.Timer(result, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));
            })
            .SelectMany(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => InvokeMethod()));

    timer.Subscribe();
}
```

Keep in mind that this will drift over time and won't fire at each minute. You need to re-adjust each time. Using `Observable.Generate` would be better.

---

```
public void Test()
{
    IObservable<Unit> timer =
        Observable
            .Generate(
                new { now = DateTimeOffset.Now, count = 0 },
                t => true,
                t => new { t.now, count = t.count + 1 },
                t => t.count,
                t => t.now.AddMinutes(t.count))
            .SelectMany(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => InvokeMethod()));

    timer.Subscribe();
}
```

Comment: could you please suggest example with `Observable.Generate`. I need to fire this each minute.

Comment: @user584018 - Done.